# How to cross-compiling node C++ addon on armv7?

Tags: android, c++, node.js

I have written a small node C++ addon. On Linux I could compile and use it (with the help of `node-gyp`). But now I'd like to test the addon on my phone(`armv7`), so I compile and link it with cross-compiler, `libv8.so` and `libnode.so`(`arm architecture`), then push it into phone.

But on `adb shell` I get the error info when using it:

```
node: symbol lookup error: /bitmap.node: undefined symbol:
_ZN6bitmap9ImageData4InitEN2v85LocalINS1_6ObjectEEE
```

which means `bitmap::ImageData::Init(v8::Local<v8::Object>)` cannot be found...

Why and how should I solve it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I just created an overview of current approaches (see section Compilation): [Viable options to running NodeJS on Android (Aug 2017)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45649995/8295283)

Answer (score 0):

I just set the appropriate `CXX` environment variables before invoking `node-gyp -arch=arm ...` and it works!

Comment: Could you please elaborate how you've set those CXX environment variables and to what? Thanks :)

Comment: @FMA Hi. You should set it to the path to your cross compiler otherwise others couldn't provide correct name mangling so that some methods (if not all) "cannot be found "

Comment: Can you share toturial or example pls. `ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND` when import my node addon